# What is the difference between a schema and a table and a database?

Tags: database, schema, definition, database-table

This is probably a n00blike (or worse) question. But I've always viewed a schema as a table definition in a database. This is wrong or not entirely correct. I don't remember much from my database courses.

Comment: In oracle schema is just referred to a user. That is when we create an user the schema will be created now we can add tables, views,indexes packages etc. as

Answer (score 314, accepted):

**schema** -> floor plan

**database** -> house

**table** -> room

Comment: A little cryptic, but not wrong; but do you really think a selfproclaimed n00b would understand that?

Comment: Good analogy.  I would change "floor plan" to "blue prints" because the schema has more than just tables, and blue prints contain the wiring and heating and plumbing.

Comment: "Schema" really just means "plan". I've seen it used to refer to the entire database, or just one table or view.

Comment: @Paul: good points. I originally wrote "blueprints" but changed it because it doesn't really connote "house" (as least not to me).

Comment: @Stein: that's pretty harsh on anbanm - he got it.  :)

Comment: surely schemas are in the database so the order is wrong? I'm specifically talking about Oracle but a database contains many schemas.

Comment: @Robert: this might be just semantic, but inside Oracle a "schema" is more synonymous with "user" or "owner".

Comment: Yea I tend to view a schema as a user in Oracle. So definitions even vary from db to db :D  How annoying.

Comment: I botch my Oracle-speak all the time, coming from SQL Server.

Comment: I agree with Paul Tomblin, I prefer "blueprints"

Comment: @GordonG: have you ever seen a blueprint for a house?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Just kudos for a nice, clean and quick answer. :)

Comment: maybe instead of floor plan, you could use "folder" for schemas

Comment: Just my two cents. In reality Schema is a user when you look at it. Database Owner ..dbo no matter SQL server, MySQL, Oracle .. everyone gets dbo means database owner.. Therefore I would change the analogy  Owner:House:Room

If I log in as the owner/resident - I can access every house I own, and the rooms inside the house. If I am not owner - I am just out of luck - or a good hack job to crack the lock.

Comment: Note that the word Schema changes definition per DBMS.

Comment: Is it right to talk about a "table's schema"? And if I did should I use that to refer to the table including it's indexes, constraints and so on, or am I just referring to the table and its columns?

Answer (score 168):

A *relation schema* is the logical definition of a table - it defines what the name of the table is, and what the name and type of each column is. It's like a plan or a blueprint. A *database schema* is the collection of relation schemas for a whole database.

A *table* is a structure with a bunch of rows (aka "tuples"), each of which has the attributes defined by the schema. Tables might also have indexes on them to aid in looking up values on certain columns.

A *database* is, formally, any collection of data. In this context, the database would be a collection of tables. A *DBMS* (Database Management System) is the software (like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc) that manages and runs a database.

Comment: A database schema also includes indexes, views, etc.

Comment: surely this is not correct. a database is not a collection of tables as such.  You can have 30 databases without having one table for instance.

Comment: @Robert - what would be the point of having a database without any tables in it?

Comment: Even if you don't have any tables, that's still a collection of tables - it's an *empty* collection of tables.

Comment: No point I can think of but the definition of a database doesn't change just because there is/isn't tables there. I have to agree I would expect to find tables in a database :)

Comment: @Robert: a collection includes the empty set.

Comment: @Ian: don't forget that a database will also have constraints - referential constraints (primary keys, foreign keys), uniqueness constraints, and check constraints.  It might also include triggers and procedures.

Comment: Also, @Robert, I think the "database" you're talking about is the term used by the commercial vendors, with a specific meaning in terms of configuration. The more "formal" definition of a database is just "a collection of data" (which includes DBMS databases, spreadsheets, etc.).

Comment: As a noob, IMHO, I feel that more than anything else, this is the answer that should actually be marked right.

Comment: plus one to jon skeet comment, regardless of what it says

Comment: very informative to point out there is a relation 'schema' and database 'schema'. Most other answers here simply ignore this and talk from the viewpoint of a particular database implementation.

Answer (score 26):

In a nutshell, a schema is the definition for the entire database, so it includes tables, views, stored procedures, indexes, primary and foreign keys, etc.

Answer (score 17):

Schema behaves seem like a parent object as seen in OOP world. so it's not a database itself. maybe [this link](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/sql-createschema.html) is useful.

But, In MySQL, the two are equivalent.  The keyword DATABASE or DATABASES
can be replaced with SCHEMA or SCHEMAS wherever it appears. Examples:

- CREATE DATABASE <=> CREATE SCHEMA
- SHOW DATABASES <=> SHOW SCHEMAS

[Documentation of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html)

SCHEMA & DATABASE terms are something DBMS dependent.

A **Table** is a set of data elements (values) that is organized using a model of vertical columns (which are identified by their name) and horizontal rows. A database contains one or more(usually) **Tables** . And you store your data in these tables. The tables may be related with one another([See here](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/relations-keys-normalization-sql-tutorial/)).

Comment: valuable answer

Answer (score 15):

This particular posting has been shown to relate to Oracle only and the definition of Schema changes when in the context of another DB.

Probably the kinda thing to just google up but FYI terms do seem to vary in their definitions which is the most annoying thing :)

In Oracle a database is a database. In your head think of this as the data files and the redo logs and the actual physical presence on the disk of the database itself (i.e. not the instance)

A Schema is effectively a user. More specifically it's a set of tables/procs/indexes etc owned by a user.  Another user has a different schema (tables he/she owns) however user can also see any schemas they have select priviliedges on. So a database can consist of hundreds of schemas, and each schema hundreds of tables.  You can have tables with the same name in different schemas, which are in the same database.

A Table is a table, a set of rows and columns containing data and is contained in schemas.

Definitions may be different in SQL Server for instance. I'm not aware of this.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

As per https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30669

> The names of all objects must be unique within some scope. Every
> database must have a unique name; the name of a schema must be unique
> within the scope of a single database, the name of a table must be
> unique within the scope of a single schema, and column names must be
> unique within a table. The name of an index must be unique within a
> database.

Answer (score 9):

From the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-schemas.html):

> A database contains one or more named schemas, which in turn contain tables. Schemas also contain other kinds of named objects, including data types, functions, and operators. The same object name can be used in different schemas without conflict; for example, both `schema1` and `myschema` can contain tables named `mytable`. Unlike databases, schemas are not rigidly separated: a user can access objects in any of the schemas in the database he is connected to, if he has privileges to do so.
>
> There are several reasons why one might want to use schemas:
>
> - To allow many users to use one database without interfering with each other.
> - To organize database objects into logical groups to make them more manageable.
> - Third-party applications can be put into separate schemas so they do not collide with the names of other objects.
>
> Schemas are analogous to directories at the operating system level, except that schemas cannot be nested.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to some of the above answers, here is my understanding based on experience with each of them:

- MySQL: `database/schema :: table`
- SQL Server: `database :: (schema/namespace ::) table`
- Oracle: `database/schema/user :: (tablespace ::) table`

Please correct me on whether tablespace is optional or not with Oracle, it's been a long time since I remember using them.

Comment: this is a good one! thanks.
lacking the PostgreSQL though :)

Answer (score 3):

A `Schema` is a collection of database objects which includes logical structures too.
It has the name of the user who owns it.
A `database` can have any number of Schema's.
One table from a database can appear in two different schemas of same name.
A user can view any schema for which they have been assigned select privilege.

Answer (score 3):

As MusiGenesis put so nicely, in most databases:

> schema : database : table :: floor plan : house : room

But, in Oracle it may be easier to think of:

schema : database : table :: owner : house : room

Answer (score 2):

More on schemas:

In SQL 2005 a schema is a way to group objects.  It is a container you can put objects into.  People can own this object.  You can grant rights on the schema.

In 2000 a schema was equivalent to a user.  Now it has broken free and is quite useful. You could throw all your user procs in a certain schema and your admin procs in another.  Grant EXECUTE to the appropriate user/role and you're through with granting EXECUTE on specific procedures.  Nice.

The dot notation would go like this:

Server.Database.Schema.Object

or

myserver01.Adventureworks.Accounting.Beans

Answer (score 2):

I try answering based on my understanding of the following analogy:

- A **database** is like the house
- In the house there are several types of rooms. Assuming that you're living in a really big house. You really don't want your living rooms, bedrooms, bathrooms, mezzanines, treehouses, etc. to look the same. They each need a blueprint to tell how to build/use them. In other words, they each need a **schema** to tell how to build/use a bathroom, for example.
- Of course, you may have several bedrooms, each looks slightly different. You and your wife/husband's bedroom is slightly different from your kids' bedroom. Each bedroom is analogous to a **table** in your database.
- A **DBMS** is like a butler in the house. He manages literally everything.

Answer (score 2):

I liked the accepted answer of comparing to a generally understood terminology. But it was a bit confusing to me. Here is my updated version of them:
Their relation from the storage/memory perspective:

```
Database (complete house) >>> schema (one room) >>> table (one closet in the room)
```

**Database:** One complete house. No copies.

**schema:** One specific room. There can be many rooms (schemas) in the house (database)

**table:** A storage closet or table inside a room. There can be many tables in a room.

Understanding it from the reduction technique:

**Deleting a database:** Razing down complete house (deleting from a computer permanently). No part of the house (database) remains after that.

**Deleting a schema:** Removing all contents of a room. There are other rooms with contents (other schemas with stored data)

**Deleting a table:** Removing contents of a closet or table inside a room (schema) of the complete house (database). So, in this room (schema), there are other tables, closet with contents stored in them.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle Schema is one user under one database,For example scott is one schema in database orcl.
      In one database we may have many schema's like scott

Answer (score 1):

Schemas contains Databases.

Databases are part of a Schema.

So, schemas > databases.

Schemas contains views, stored procedure(s), database(s), trigger(s) etc.

Answer (score 1):

A schema is not a plan for the entire database. It is a plan/container for a subset of objects (ex.tables) inside a a database. 
  
This goes to say that you can have multiple objects(ex. tables) inside one database which don't neccessarily fall under the same functional category. So you can group them under various schemas and give them different user access permissions. 
 
 That said, I am unsure whether you can have one table under multiple schemas. The Management Studio UI gives a dropdown to assign a schema to a table, and hence making it possible to choose only one schema. I guess if you do it with TSQL, it might create 2 (or multiple) different objects with different object Ids.

Answer (score 0):

A database **schema** is a way to logically group objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc. Think of a schema as a container of objects.
And tables are collections of rows and columns.
combination of all tables makes a db.

Comment: Those first sentences are the exact same.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29042133/2308683

Answer (score 0):

Okay, some of this you already know. The database holds the data, but the schema tells you how to store it. The physical equivalent might be database:schema::warehouse:shelves. Maybe the shelves are also organized by sections (like a library).

The schema is basically *how* to structure the database:

- What kind of "schema objects" should be in the database?
- What should they be called
- What "`type`" of value should they have?

A table is one kind of "schema object." Others include views, operators, stored functions, users, roles, directories (these can be sub-divided, but don't worry about that for the basic understanding).