# Merging Two databases with the same exact structure [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just had my site hacked and they were able to do some damage to my current database.

Anyway, I have a backup from few days ago. The problem is that the current database had a few thousand more posts and threads / users.

I am simply wondering how I could possibly go about merging the two databases?

The two databases have the exact structure, and I want the backup to overwrite any record from the current database, just that I want the current database to populate any new records like posts, threads, users and such.

I know you can merge two tables, if they have the exact structure, but what about two databases that have the same structure?

Comment: `REPLACE INTO table (id, col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), ...`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a schema `s1` and a schema `s2`.

To insert all rows of a table in s1 into a table in s2, while overwriting existing lines, you can use:

```
REPLACE INTO s2.table_name
SELECT * FROM s1.table_name;
```

If you do not want to touch existing lines:

```
INSERT INTO s2.table_name
SELECT * FROM s1.table_name
ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE;
```

Comment: By schema do you mean database?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Though the word "database" may be "more right" in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298739/what-is-the-difference-between-a-schema-and-a-table-and-a-database

Comment: ON Duplicate, does that mean if any of the columns in the table have a value that is being injected then it wouldn't overwrite right?

Comment: I'm also getting this error when I try the second code. 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE' at line 3

Comment: If you supply `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` and a row with the same primary key is already in the table, then the insertion is skipped for that line.

Comment: Can you please paste the exact statement that you have executed?

Comment: `INSERT INTO shadygam_xfRestored.xf_user
SELECT * FROM shadygam_forum.xf_user
ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE;`

Comment: Primary Key? is that a certain column that is given this attribute in the table?

Comment: Hm, I do not see an error in your statement. Sorry. The primary key is often a special, synthetic (autoincrement) column. But it can be combination multiple existing columns (mostly in N-to-M mappings).

Comment: Still giving me an error, could I use something other than "IGNORE" to possibly overcome this error?

Comment: Possible to ignore a match if two column's values match? 

for example `ON DUPLICATE table_1 OR table_2 IGNORE;`  I don't know the syntax at all, but if the values of one table or the other match, don't overwrite.

Comment: The syntax is `ON DUPLICATE KEY ...`, KEY is part of the keyword.

Comment: Well, the error presists, so I was just trying to brainstorm another way of going about it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

there was some ways to do it:
1.) use  Command line tools like [schema Sync](http://schemasync.org/) and [mysql diff](https://bitbucket.org/stepancheg/mysql-diff/wiki/Home)

2.) or Using SQLyog

find out more here
http://blog.webyog.com/2012/10/16/so-how-do-you-sync-your-database-schema/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE did not work. Instead I found

INSERT IGNORE ta2_table
SELECT * FROM ta1_table;

worked like a charm