# Can we have two Postgres databases in same schema?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-schema

I hope someone can help me to learn about Postgres schema and databases.

I have Postgres database called **db1** and it has table calls **table1**.
all these objects are in default schema called **public**.

Then I created another database called **db2** and created another table with same name **table1**.

I didn't got any error but both tables are in same schema called **public**.

I created indexes for both of these tables and they both refer the table as **public.table1**.

I wonder a setup like this will give issue or not? If yes, then should I create different schemas for each database if I'm going to use same table names in all databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres a database is the highest level "container". Then schemas follow. There can be schemas with the same name in different databases (but not in the same database). The other databases won't "see" them. So there is no problem in your setup.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we have two Postgres databases in same schema?

The answer is no. The relevant PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html) shows the hierarchy:

> database.schema.table

This diagram (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902123/599390) answer) is useful to visualise the relationship:

[image]